# How does LaTeX determine its default line spacing/why is this newcommand's line spacing different depending where I use it?

Tags: spacing, macros, line-spacing

I know how I can increase/decrease/alter line spacing in LaTeX but it feels like a hack to manually set `\vspace{-5pt}` every time I want two lines to be closer together and I think I could come up with a better solution if I understood why LaTeX does what it does in the first place.

For example, in building my resume I have the following newenvironments to define section headers, projects, and bullet points:

```
% A section:itemized is a main section with a header and some items within it
\newenvironment{section:itemized}[1]{
  {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\Large\scshape#1}
  \begin{itemize}
  }{
  \end{itemize}
}

% Displays info about a job and holds list items describing what  
% projects were completed there
\newenvironment{item:experience:itemized}[4]{
\item[]
  \textbf{\scshape#1},  \hfill \textbf{#2} \\ % Show company and dates
  \textit{\scshape#3}\hfill #4 % Show position and location
  \begin{itemize}
  }{
  \end{itemize}
} 

% This is a project heading and requires list items that can be bullet
% points describing the project
\newenvironment{item:project:itemized}[3]{
  \itemprojectandtech{#1}{#2} \\
  \textit{#3} 
  \begin{itemize}
  }{
  \end{itemize}
}

% An itembulleted is a simple list element
\newcommand{\itembulleted}[1]{
\item \begin{flushleft} #1 \end{flushleft}
}
```

In one place in my resume, I use a `section:itemized` to create an Experience section. Within it are `item:experience:itemized` items and they all contain `item:project:itemized` items which hold `itembulleted` details about the project.  Elsewhere in my resume I use a `section:itemized` to create an Other Projects section that holds `project:itemized` items which hold `itembulleted` details.

Where this is done in the Other Projects section, there is a wider line space before and between each bulleted item than when this is done in the Experience section.

Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

Here is sample code:

```
\begin{section:itemized}{Experience}
  \begin{item:experience:itemized}{Super Company}{September 2016 - present}{Head of Stuff}{Mytown, USA}

  \begin{item:project:itemized}{Cool Project}{Technology, other technology}{Thing that's going away}
    \itembulleted{Here are a bunch of words that describe this project.}
        \itembulleted{And even more words because it was a really cool project and there are things to say.}
  \end{item:project:itemized}  
  \end{item:experience:itemized}

\end{section:itemized}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{section:itemized}{Other Projects}

    \begin{item:project:itemized}{Cool Project}{Technology, other technology}{Thing that's going away}
    \itembulleted{Here are a bunch of words that describe this project.}
    \itembulleted{And even more words because it was a really cool project and there are things to say.}
  \end{item:project:itemized}
```

Comment: You will probably get an answer here soon. But for future questions, please post a MWE - a minimal complete compilable example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The list - related environments `itemize`, `enumerate` and `description` use level  specific vertical spacings, so the spacings are different from one level deeper down to the inner levels... and you have nested environments here

Comment: it is rather hard to follow your fragments, please fix the question to have a single document that people can run to see the issue.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, do you want to make that comment an answer? It's the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example of the O.P. shows nested `itemize` environments, which means that the `\item` commands appear on different levels.

The `itemize` environment has different spacing values for the individual elastical lengths that control the vertical distances of  the `\item` - lines, those
are

- `\topsep`
- `\itemsep`
- `\parsep`
- `\partopsep`

The `\topsep` together with `\partopsep` and `\parskip` controls the spacing between both the top of the environment and the first `\item` content and the bottom of the environment, i.e. the last line of the last `\item` and the beginning of the next non-environment content.

`\itemsep+`\parsep`` is responsible for the separation between the last line of an `\item` content and the next `\item`.

---

This small document shows the standard values for `article`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\niceintern}[1]{%
  \texttt{#1}: \the\csname #1\endcsname
}
\newcommand{\niceoutput}{%
 \niceintern{itemsep}

 \niceintern{parsep}

 \niceintern{partopsep}

 \niceintern{topsep}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

   \item First level 

  \niceoutput
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Second level 

  \niceoutput
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Third level

     \niceoutput

      \begin{itemize}
      \item Fourth level

        \niceoutput

      \end{itemize}
     \end{itemize}
   \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. This was very helpful, especially seeing it with the screenshot.

Comment: @Reagankm: You're welcome. I hope you know how to adapt the spacings. You should use the `enumitem` package which allows a better control of the `itemize` related spacings